# JQuery appendTo() to html() to allow replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appendto

I have the following

```
$('.toggle_questions').appendTo('#'+sectionId).show();
```

Which works perfectly to append my div (`.toggle_questions`). However, I want it to replace rather than add each time.

From my understanding this is done through `html()` rather than `appendTo()` ?  I have only found examples adding simple `<p>` codes and not actual `<div>` 's

I have changed it to this but it won't seem to do anything:

```
$('#'+sectionId).show().html($('.toggle_questions')).show();
```

The `show()` is needed as it is set to hidden to start with.

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would save the content of `$('.toggle_questions')` on every occurrence and apply it like this:

```
var content = $('.toggle_questions').html();
$('#' + sectionId).html(content).show()
```

It's a much cleaner code and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you similar to Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's approach but using a variable. I'll definitely clean up my code using this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass html string in to [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/),

```
$('#'+sectionId).html($('.toggle_questions').html()).show();
```

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) wont accept jquery object as its parameter.

But `appendTo()` will move the original object. If you want to do the same thing using `.html()`, then you have to remove it manually after setting the html string.